# Why do I get "Cannot Complete This Action" when I add a Discussion Category?

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, community

I created a subsite with a template that had the Community Features turned on. When I go to add a Category in the Discussion Board, I get the following error message.
[image]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with SharePoint Online: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2880772

Do not save a community site as a template and create a new site from it.